# Incorrect rotation from two views in one nib

Tags: ios, subview, nib

Hope someone can set me straight. I have a utility app with one ViewController and a nib with two views. The first view is for custom transcription, and the second just has a TexView for the user to jot notes with the system keyboard. I have an IBAction method that does a setView:noteView to display my second view. However, when noteView is set, it appears upside down. The application does allow for normal Portait and rotated views, no landscape, but I'm not sure why the view would load upside down?????

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the issue was, but the easiest way to resolve my problem was to create a storyboard, and copy the views from my original nib to the storyboard. I hadn't used storyboards yet, and didn't realize how easy it was. The ViewTransitions example code from the Apple Documentation has some really cool transitions in it, and illustrates how to set up a single controller - multiple view application.